# Giant pigeon crashes into the ground, normal size pigeon lies dead

Tags: story-identification

There was this book I read while being in a school in Germany. I can narrow that time down to 1991 to 1994. I borrowed it at the library there and I think it was no new book then, probably over ten years old at least.  I know I read the book in German at the time.

What I remember about the story is a bit vague. I remember the protagonist being a guy who somehow interacts with some professor. Then there were giant animals around the world I think, the scene I remember most was a normal sized pigeon lying in a crater dead where the former giant pigeon crashed in with its head.

I think a girl was involved, too and if I am not all wrong the protagonist probably was around middle to late teen.

There was a ray involved that was pointed at the animals. And it could be possible, but that one really is vague, that it only involved birds.

The story was as I believe the only one in the book and it could be between 80 to 200 pages (not so sure, really).